# React js component, how to add json feed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, components

I trying to create react component that accepts the feed URL as props and then shows the data. 
in the code :
1-LeagueInfo  child component of LeageMatch.
2-LeageMatch  parent component it is the main component and I pass the feed to LeaguInfo (it's child) as props in the index.js

`

```js
/////LeagueInfo-Child compnent////
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class LeagueInfo extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoading : false,
            league : '',
            feed : this.props.feed
        }
        this.apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
        console.log(this.apiUrl);
         this.API =this.apiUrl+this.state.feed+".json"    

    }
    componentDidMount(){
     // const API =this.apiUrl+this.state.feed+".json"  ???      
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        fetch(this.API,{
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then(data=>{
             let  league = <p> <img src={"feedurl"+(data.competitionId)+".png"} /> {data.competitionName}</p>;
              
              this.setState({league: league});
          })
          .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <h2>
           {this.state.league}
           </h2>
        );
    }
}

export default LeagueInfo;

/////LeageMatch-Parent compnent////
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LeagueInfo from './LeagueInfo'



class LeagueMatch extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <LeagueInfo feed={this.props.leagueInfofeed} />
    ...);
    }
 }
}

export default LeagueMatch;

//index.js
const LeagueMatchWrapper = document.getElementById('leaguematch-wrapper');
ReactDOM.render(<LeagueMatch  leagueInfofeed="league"/>, LeagueMatchWrapper);
```

`
in the code
I'm new to react, soi have some questions :

1. is this the correct way to add the feed to a component.
2. should I add the feed to the state of the component as `feed :
   this.props.feed`.
3. if i declare the feed API in the componentDidMount() as : `const API =this.apiUrl+this.state.feed+".json"` when the component render first it shows the correct data then it hides it, can I know why?
4. if the feed updated react will automatically re-render the component or I have to add some lister

Comment: Can you give more information on how your UI is? Will there be multiple league infos? Will there be different API calls for all of them?

Comment: @SatejS , yes there will be multiple leagues info in each page that is why I wanted to add it to the props so i  can pass different feed for each component.